# Custom OWIN CookieAuthenticationProvider fails on 1st/cold boot

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, owin

We have a custom cookie auth provider that puts sets the auth cookie to bear a hostname like `.domain.com` instead of `domain.com` or `my.domain.com`. We do it so the cookies work across all subdomains and the domains. It's as simple as shown below.

***Issue***

On the very FIRST attempt after app cold start, the cookie STILL bears the domain `my.domain.com` (our logins are on `my.domain.com`) DESPITE setting it to `.domain.com` after executing the `SubdomainCookieAuthentication` code below (checked with breakpoints). On subsequent login attempts, the cookie hostname is fine.

***Question***

How can I fix this so it works even on the first attempt?

***Code***

Custom cookie auth

```
public class SubdomainCookieAuthentication : CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override void ResponseSignIn(CookieResponseSignInContext context)
    {
        // We need to add a "." in front of the domain name to 
        // allow the cookie to be used on all sub-domains too
        var hostname = context.Request.Uri.Host;
        // works for www.google.com => google.com
        // will FAIL for www.google.co.uk (gives co.uk) but doesn't apply to us
        var dotTrimmedHostname = Regex.Replace(hostname, @"^.*(\.\S+\.\S+)", "$1");
        context.Options.CookieDomain = dotTrimmedHostname;            
        base.ResponseSignIn(context);
    }
}
```

This is initialized inside the Owin startup class as follows

Class: `Startup`

File: `App_start\Startup.Auth.cs`

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new SubdomainCookieAuthentication()
    });
}
```

Comment: have you ever fixed this?

Comment: Seems like bug, time to report github issues

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with the Cookie Domain not getting set on the first attempt using the ResponseSignIn method. I was able to resolve this by updating the Owin libraries to 3.x and using the new CookieManager to set the Domain. Found this solution from this post:

[How is Owin able to set the Asp.Net Identity authentication cookies after the Application_EndRequest stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252478/how-is-owin-able-to-set-the-asp-net-identity-authentication-cookies-after-the-ap)

```
public class ChunkingCookieManagerWithSubdomains : ICookieManager
{
    private readonly ChunkingCookieManager _chunkingCookieManager;

    public ChunkingCookieManagerWithSubdomains()
    {
        _chunkingCookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
    }

    public string GetRequestCookie(IOwinContext context, string key)
    {
        return _chunkingCookieManager.GetRequestCookie(context, key);
    }

    public void AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options.Domain = context.Request.Uri.GetHostWithoutSubDomain();
        _chunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(context, key, value, options);
    }

    public void DeleteCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options.Domain = context.Request.Uri.GetHostWithoutSubDomain();
        _chunkingCookieManager.DeleteCookie(context, key, options);
    }
}

public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static string GetHostWithoutSubDomain(this Uri url)
    {
        if (url.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
        {
            string host = url.Host;
            if (host.Split('.').Length > 2)
            {
                int lastIndex = host.LastIndexOf(".");
                int index = host.LastIndexOf(".", lastIndex - 1);
                return host.Substring(index + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return host;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, register it in Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ...
        CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManagerWithSubdomains(), 
        ...
    }
);
```